# Get the row with minimum value of column1 and in column2 greater then 100 DataFram

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

im a begginer with DataFrame.
I have task that i need to write a query for DataFram

This is how my dataframe look like:

[image]

I need the first row that has minimum age and points is bigger then 100.

i tried to use min() function but i dont know how to use anther query?

How to build the DF

```
dict1 ={'Driver':['Hamilton', 'Vettel', 'Raikkonen', 
              'Verstappen', 'Bottas', 'Ricciardo', 
              'Hulkenberg', 'Perez', 'Magnussen',  
              'Sainz', 'Alonso', 'Ocon', 'Leclerc', 
              'Grosjean', 'Gasly', 'Vandoorne', 
              'Ericsson', 'Stroll', 'Hartley', 'Sirotkin'], 
                
    'Points':[408, 320, 251, 249, 247, 170, 69, 62, 56, 
               53, 50, 49, 39, 37, 29, 12, 9, 6, 4, 1], 
                 
    'Age':[33, 31, 39, 21, 29, 29, 31, 28, 26, 24, 37, 
                  22, 21, 32, 22, 26, 28, 20, 29, 23]} 
                    

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Expected result row3: `Verstappen 249 21`

because he is a yungest age and points is bigger then `100`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`df.idxmin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) for this:

Find all rows with `Points > 100` and from these rows find the index of row with `min` Age:

```
In [3124]: ix = df[df.Points.gt(100)].Age.idxmin()
```

Use the above index to find the row from the df:

```
In [3126]: df = df.loc[ix]

In [3127]: df
Out[3127]: 
Driver    Verstappen
Points           249
Age               21
Name: 3, dtype: object
```